# Mandar correo cuando se cambia una celda y se cumplen varias condiciones

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He estado tratando de buscar una respuesta para este problema específico y no consigo encontrar la respuesta adecuada. Tengo una hoja de cálculo y quiero que mande un correo cada vez que se modifique los datos de las celdas en la columna L de una hoja en concreto, tengo un activador de proyecto para este caso en concreto que dispara la función al editar la hoja de cálculo. Éste es el resultado:

```js
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn()
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "blablabla@blabla.com";
  var message = '';
  //column L is number 12, when the result is zero it won´t enter the if
  if(column-12){ 
  //do nothing
    message='no hago nada'
  }
  else{
  //Only if I am in this specific sheet
    if(sheet.getName()=='Olmedo Trabajos de Pepe'){
    //Only if the cell is not empty
      if(cellvalue!=''){
        var subject =' Fotos de promoción: ' + sheet.getRange('G'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
        var body = ' Promoción: ' + sheet.getRange('G'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() +'\n Pedido de Olmedo ' + sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '\n Oferta Panorama ' + sheet.getRange('m'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() +'\n Ya tiene fotos en la dirección \n' + sheet.getRange('L'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
        //Then I´ll send an email with the information from the table.
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Como podéis ver, fruto de mi desconocimiento de Javascript hay cosas que como poco son feas, como hacer 3 if en vez de uno porque no he dado con la forma de concatenar todas las condiciones en uno sólo (intenté con "&&").

Comment: Buenas Pablo, bienvenido. Voto para cerrar esta pregunta por estar en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es el español. Si [editas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/45701/edit) tu pregunta para traducirla retiraré mi voto. O puedes hacer la pregunta en http://stackoverlflow.com . Un saludo

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta al español, o formula esta pregunta en [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Hecho, perdonad, no me di cuenta.

Comment: Pablo, bien por publicar la pregunta en español. La pregunta está muy amplia porque abarca varios temas.  Considera ver el playlist de videos en español de introducción a Google Apps Script (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7y43_eJEnJW3kTHRPCpVY9Ey1IIJOzzb) y luego ajustar tu pregunta a un sólo tema y los otros publicarlos como nuevas pregunas.

Comment: Gracias Rubén, me miraré la playlist parece que puede ser muy interesante.

Comment: No hay de que @Pablo_1985. Me tomé la libertad de eliminar los últimos enunciados para dejar la pregunta en un sólo tema. Si ya has encontrado como revisar el transcript de la ejecución agrega si tu script se detiene debido a un error y la descripción de este. Más detalles en [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Va un ejemplo de lo que sería un script a ser llamado cuando ocurre un cambio. El script envía un mensaje cuando se modifica una de tres celdas, `B1`,`B2`,`B3` de la `Hoja 1` y que cada una de estas cumplen con una condición específica.

> Nota: Para facilitar el seguimiento se obtienen los datos de las celdas individualmente. Para un desempeño óptimo, reducir el número de llamadas a la API, por ejemplo usando [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

```
function enviarEmail() {
  //Iniciamos
  //Validar si hay cuota disponible. En caso contrario avisar al usuario y terminar.
  var cuotaDisponible = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log('Cuota disponible previa: %s', cuotaDisponible);
  if(cuotaDisponible < 1) {
    Browser.msgBox('No queda cuota disponible por hoy. Intenta más tarde.');
    return;
  }
  // Obtener la celda actual
  var celdaActual = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  /*
   * En caso de que la celda actual sea B1, B2 o B3 
   * y que se cumplan otras condiciones, enviar un
   * mensaje
   */
  switch (celdaActual.getA1Notation()){
    case 'B1':
    case 'B2':
    case 'B3':
    var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var hoja = libro.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
    //Valor B1
    var destinatario = hoja.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
    //Valor B2
    var asunto = hoja.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    //Valor B3
    var cuerpo = hoja.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
    //Validar que se cumplen las condiciones requeridas
    if(
        // Dirección de correo. Sólo validar que la longitud mínima sea 3
        destinatario.length > 3 && 
        // Asunto. Validar que tenga al menos un caracter
        asunto.length > 1 && 
        // Cuerpo. Validar que tenga al menos un caracter
        cuerpo.length > 1
    ){
      //Enviar mensaje
      MailApp.sendEmail(destinatario, asunto, cuerpo);
      //Aviso al usuario
      Browser.msgBox('Mensaje enviado');
    } else {
      //Aviso al usuario
      Browser.msgBox('No se envió el mensaje');
    }
    /*
     * En caso de agregar otros casos, prevenir que se ejecuten
     * "sin querer"
     */
    break;
  }
  //Terminamos
  return;
}
```

Nota: He creado un gist con el código de esta respuesta -> https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/6015c00bff61a994bb0af6d97ec158a2

Comment: Gracias Rubén, esto me ayuda mucho!